# AJAX to load page

Tags: php, ajax

I have a page which has been contains HTML, PHP and JavaScript, I also have another page which is very similar but uses different variables; one page maps users hometowns to a map and the other maps users locations to a map. I have tried simply linking between the two as a normal link in HTML but because it is on a Facebook canvas I get an error about the URL when I try to go to the other page, im therefore looking to load the pages using AJAX. I understand how to replace div contents using AJAX but I cant seem to find anything about loading a whole page, I kind of need to do this as the 2 different pages have different variables in PHP.

Would there be a better way to do this or is there no easy way? Ive never really used AJAX before so I dont really know how to go about doing this, I suppose I could include variables and PHP calls in one file but I imagine it would take quite a long time and the code would get quite messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code to load the html page inside a div

```
$.ajax({ url: requrl,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                $('#DivId').html(response);
            },
            error: function (response, error) {
alert(error);
            }
        });
```

Based on required condition, you can pass different url to load different HTML page inside a div!